# How to check if thread will run fine in my code

Tags: java, java-threads

```
 public Boolean fetchGit(final Map obj) {
        Boolean taskStatus = false;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    fetchGitThread(obj);


                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(GitTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

                }
            }
        }).start();
        return true;
    }
```

Like in this code what if I caught an exemption. I'm not able to return anything form void run and can't use taskStatus variable. Please advice me here.

Comment: Just use ExecutorService and convert your Runnable to [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible ways i could think of.

1.) Use `AtomicBoolean` instead of Boolean, then you can modify the value in your `run`method.

2.) Create a class that extends Thread and implement a `boolean getStatus()` which returns your status.

**BUT**

The real problem you have, is that you are starting a Thread, and want the response of this Thread in your `fetchGit` method. This makes no sense at all.
You could probably add a Callback as 2nd parameter to get notified when the method is finished, and remove `boolean` return type.

Comment: What if I just call a function in the thread and then in function use try and catch?

Comment: And can you please show me an example?
"The real problem you have, is that you are starting a Thread, and want the response of this Thread in your fetchGit method. This makes no sense at all. You could probably add a Callback as 2nd parameter to get notified when the method is finished, and remove boolean return type."
I'm new in java that's why. 
Thanks